# How to cause an assignment to a monitored variable in perl to print a message?

Tags: perl

My objective is that each time a value is assigned to a "monitored" variable then I want to:

1. Register that change in a log file or display it in a status area
2. Keep the code tidy.

A real world example would be the cursor position in an editor being changed in the status bar changing as the cursor is moved around the document.

I understand that objective 1. is easily satisfied with the following snippet.

```
$a = 52;
print LOG "\$a = [$a]\n";
```

My preference is that the code looks like this:

```
$a = 52;
```

And somewhere else (an object, procedure, overloaded operator) the printing magically occurs.

Comment: You can overload the `=` operator, but only if it is on the right side of your variable. You'd have to make `$a` a class. But it won't help here, because you want to grab if it is assigned a new value with `=`. Anyway, nice explanation of overloading: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=33772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tied variables have a lot of overhead. Using tied variables, it will take something like a hundred times longer to read from the variable. It's easy to avoid some of this overhead with much more targeted magic.

```
use Variable::Magic qw( wizard cast );

cast $i, wizard( set => sub { print "\$i = [${$_[0]}]\n"; } );

$i = 52;  # Outputs $i = [52]
```

Comment: (Avoided `$a` since I consider it reserved for `sort`.)

Comment: I profiled the code using Devel::NYTProf and Variable::Magic proved to be approximately 3-4 times quicker than Tie::Scalar in my test environment.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by tie-ing your scalar variables to a package that handles the logging. Tie-ing allows you to define subs that get called in order to actually store, fetch, etc. values.

See [perltie](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-Scalars) and [Tie::Scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Scalar.html).

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package LogScalar;
use Tie::Scalar;
our @ISA=qw(Tie::StdScalar);

sub STORE {
        my ($this, $value)=@_;
        print "LOG: Storing $value in $this\n";
        $this->SUPER::STORE($value)
}

package main;

my $v;
tie $v, 'LogScalar';

$v=100;

print "v = $v\n";
```

Output:

```
LOG: Storing 100 in LogScalar=SCALAR(0x1ff0890)
v = 100
```